# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Hello i have been tyring to deserealize this json response and then loop through the objects so i can save them in my database but keeps getting this error.
Here are my classes

```
public class Details
{
    public string ConID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LA { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public object ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public object ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public object ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public object BcNumber { get; set; }
    public string CID { get; set; }
}

public class Notice
{
    public string NoticeID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Details> details { get; set; }
    public List<Notice> Notice { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

//Here is the Json Response

```
[
    {
        "details": {
            "ConID": "1427093",
            "Name": "David Mark",
            "LA": "LAGOS",
            "Sector": "SERVICES",
            "Category": "LARGE",
            "Email": "",
            "Phone": "",
            "Address": "VI LAGOS",
            "ContactPerson": null,
            "ContactPhone": null,
            "ContactEmail": null,
            "BcNumber": null,
            "CID": "11111111111"
        },
        "Notice": {
            "NoticeID": "null"
        },
        "ResponseCode": "00",
        "ResponseMessage": "Successfull"
    },
 {
        "details": {
            "ConID": "1427093",
            "Name": "Samuel King",
            "LA": "NAIROBI",
            "Sector": "SERVICES",
            "Category": "SMALL",
            "Email": "",
            "Phone": "",
            "Address": "VI LAGOS",
            "ContactPerson": null,
            "ContactPhone": null,
            "ContactEmail": null,
            "BcNumber": null,
            "CID": "11112112121"
        },
        "Notice": {
            "NoticeID": "null"
        },
        "ResponseCode": "00",
        "ResponseMessage": "Successfull"
    }]
```

Here is the part i tried to deserialize the json

```
HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://xxxxx");
HttpResponseMessage response = webClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSON);
}
```

How do i desearlize that json response to match my class

Comment: `but keeps getting this error.` I don't see any errors..

Comment: Your json is an array of objects, you deserialize into a single object.  Fix that

Comment: You can use Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste JSON as classes in Visual Studio to generate the JSON classes. If you have some kind of typo in your classes this will help you find it.

Comment: @maccettura please how do i do that  i used var _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSON); but i still get cannot deserialze object

Comment: @DavidEgbebunmi I address this in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues.

The first is that your classes dont accurately represent your Json.

The two problem properties are in your `RootObject` class:

```
public List<Details> details { get; set; }
public List<Notice> Notice { get; set; }
```

Your json shows these as a single object, not an array of objects.  Your code should instead be:

```
public Details details { get; set; }
public Notice Notice { get; set; }
```

The second problem is your deserializtion code.  Your json is a *list* of objects, not a single one.  So your code should be:

```
List<RootObject> _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSON);
```

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cw53GW)

Comment: Thanks a bunch you just saved my day, the problem was from my classes.

Answer (score 0):

As @maccettura suggests, you might have to do something like this:

```
var _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSON);
```

This is because you want to deserialize a list of root objects, not a single object.